# How to grep two numbers from the same line at different places using bash?

Tags: command-line, bash, grep, text-processing

I want to `grep` 2 numbers from the same line in the example below:

```
// ExampleFile.txt
solver.cpp:229] Iteration 2000, loss = 0.305721
solver.cpp:245]     Train net output #0: accuracy = 0.926112
solver.cpp:245]     Train net output #1: accuracy = 0.723957
solver.cpp:245]     Train net output #2: accuracy = 0.599623
sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 2000, lr = 0.000227383
solver.cpp:229] Iteration 2020, loss = 0.294722
solver.cpp:245]     Train net output #0: accuracy = 0.855208
solver.cpp:245]     Train net output #1: accuracy = 0.71616
solver.cpp:245]     Train net output #2: accuracy = 0.619429
```

I need the number to the right of "solver.cpp:229] Iteration " and to the right of ", loss = ". I need to get both numbers at the same time such that my resulting file looks like this:

```
// ResultFile.txt
2000 0.305721
2020 0.294722
```

I only know how to get one of the numbers using grep like this

```
grep ", loss = " ExampleFile.txt | sed -e "s/.* //" > ResultFile.txt
```

Does anyone know how to get the second number simultaneously?

Comment: Do you want the pair of numbers from only lines with "cpp:229"? Or do you also want the one with "cpp:106"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One possible way...

```
% grep 'solver.cpp:229' ExampleFile.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 3,6 | tr -d ','
2000 0.305721
2020 0.294722
```

Comment: It works. Thanks. I know that `cut` cuts the string at every `' '` (space). But what does the last command do? (`tr -d ','`)

Comment: @mcExchange it deletes the comma that would otherwise remain

Answer (score 7):

I lost `grep` but here it is with `sed`

```
$ sed -nr 's/.*Iteration ([0-9]+).*loss.*( [0-9]+.*)/\1\2/p' ExampleFile.txt
2000 0.305721
2020 0.294722
```

- `-n` don't print until we ask for something
- `-r` use ERE so I don't have to escape the `()` and `+` metacharacters
- `s` search and replace `/old/new/`
- `.*` matches any (or no) characters
- `([0-9]+)` parentheses to keep this part of the pattern `[0-9]` a number `+` one or more occurrences of the preceding character.
- `\1\2` backreferences to the patterns saved earlier with parentheses
- `p` print the bits we want to see

If the output is what you want, redirect it to your outfile:

```
sed -nr 's/.*Iteration ([0-9]+).*loss.*( [0-9]+.*)/\1\2/p' ExampleFile.txt > ResultFile.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

With awk specify **F**ield separator as ',' comma and 'space' and match those lines which contain "Iteration" in, next print the columns #3 and #7 (or $NF as last column instead of $7)

```
awk -F'[, ]' '/Iteration/ {print $3,$7}' infile
```

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -nE '/\].*?(\d+),.*loss = (\d+\.\d+)/ and say "$1 $2"' infile
```

- if (line matches the regular expression), print the relevant groups.